# Display article image and title on the Homepage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a JSON file where I store article title, image and content. I want to display article title and image on the homepage and when the user clicks on it, they will be taken to the article page just as you see in most news sites.

Comment: Hi, can you just elaborate your question more? Take a screenshot of your work or post a piece of code for example.

Comment: no like number that would be used as id ?

Comment: We are going to need a lot more information for what it is you have attempted and are trying to do. Right now, your request is super vague and could be achieved in a multitude of ways with a multitude of tech stacks. Please be way more specific so that we can actually help you.

Comment: like in the BuzzFeed home page, you see article title and image, when you click you will be taken to the article page. my question is how do I create the homepage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how we parse json data using jQuery.

But usually, we use a server-side language (that you didn't mentioned in your question tags) like php to render the homepage content.

It's almost doing the same thing except with a different syntax. Menus that are hardcoded from server-side are better understood by search engines because they don't have to execute such script to access to this content and they would just parse a plain HTML code.

---

```js
var data='[{"id":"1","title":"Forbes","content":"Forbes Magazine...","image":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/d/d2/Forbes_%28magazine%29_cover.jpg","url":"page1.php"},{"id":"2","title":"NatGeo","content":"National Geo bla bla","image":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/46/National_Geographic_Traveler_december_12.png","url":"page2.php"},{"id":"3","title":"Golf Digest","content":"Golf news and events...","image":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/48/GolfDigestCover.jpg","url":"page3.php"},{"id":"4","title":"Travel+Leisure","content":"A trip somewhere...","image":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/c/ce/Travel_%2B_Leisure_magazine_cover.jpg","url":"page4.php"}]';

$(document).ready(function() {
 $.each(JSON.parse(data), function (index, value) {
        $('#links').append('<li><a href="'+value.url+'" title="'+value.title+'"><img src="'+value.image+'"><a><p>'+value.content+'</p></li>')
    });
});
```

```css
ul{
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0 auto;
}
img{
width:30%;
}
li{
display:inline-block;
float:left;
padding-right:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="links">

</ul>
```

[Notice] If you are getting the json with ajax or [getjson](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), you need to remove `JSON.parse(data)` and use just `data` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much, exactly what I needed.

Comment: You can set it as accepted answer then :) You are welcome !